# rules for programname.c not found

Tags: autoconf, automake

I am trying to run automake and autoconf in my project. However when I run make, I get an error "no rules to make inz.c required by inz.o". However I don't have inz.c in my project. I guess it might by an error in configuration, but it is my first time using autoconf/automake, so I'd like to kindly ask for assistance. I am running under Linux
The sturcture is as following:

```
inz (main folder)
-configure.ac
-inz.cbp
-inz.depend
-inz.layout
-Makefile.am
--src\main.cpp
--src\main.hpp
--src\packetcapture.cpp
--src\packetcapture.hpp
--src\packetprocess.cpp
--src\packetprocess.hpp
--src\Makefile.am
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([inz], 1.0)
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am:

```
SUBDIRS = src
dist_doc_DATA = README.md
```

src\Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = inz
inz_sources = main.cpp packetcapture.cpp packetprocess.cpp
include_HEADERS = main.hpp packetcapture.hpp packetprocess.hpp
```

commands to compile the project itself: (it also uses -lndpi -lpthread and -lpcap)

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -Wunused -g -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Iinclude -I./ -c /inz/src/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/main.o
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -Wunused -g -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Iinclude -I./ -c /inz/src/packetcapture.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/packetcapture.o
```

commands I run to confiugre automake/autoconf (from the main folder):

```
autoreconf --install
cd build
../configure
make
```

Comment: wag: x\y should be x\\y; or better yet x/y -- most msdos programs know the proper path separator.

Comment: it is under linux

Comment: Sounds like automake might be confused - If you change `bin_PROGRAMS = inz` to `bin_PROGRAMS = test`, does it fail with `"no rules to make test.c required by test.o"` ?. It could have something to do with the fact that you have a file in your root dir starting with `inz`.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact fail error when I change bin_PROGRAMS. Maybe the problem is with the cbp file generated by Code::Blocks?
It is not the cbp issue, I tried

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with variable names because they are case sensitive.

You're declaring `inz_sources`, but that's not a special variable for automake. `inz_SOURCES` would be.

Without a special `_SOURCES` variable, automake will go on to assume that `inz` is built from `inz.c`. But you don't have that file so it fails.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try

Comment: Everything works well, but how can I add dependecy on external libraries?
Something along -lndpi or -lpthread

Comment: You need to use the `_LDADD` variable.

Comment: See https://autotools.io/whosafraid.html for a minimal autotools-based project design.

But those are also probably more questions, than what you're asking here.